# How to send mail in WampServer using hMailServer

Tags: php, email, wampserver

I have mail function in php which looks like:

```
<?php
  $admin_email = "admin@gmail.com";
  $email ="myemail@gmail.com";
  $subject = "hellow ord";
  $comment = "cmt";

  try{
    $th=mail($admin_email, $subject, $comment, "From:" . $email);
    if($th)
      echo "gg";
    else    
      echo "error_message";
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
    echo $e->message();
  }
?>
```

I have Wamp server to run it. I have configured hMailServer by seeing a post on Stack Overflow but when I run the above code I get:

```
Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 SMTP authentication is required...
```

Do I need to set up anything before using mail function?

Comment: Show us the amendments you made to the [mail function] section of your `php.ini` file.

Comment: You cannot use an SMTP account with a password as it is not possible to setup smtp authentication from the `php.ini` file. So I create a user account on hMailer with no password so that removed this issue. Then make a catchall account which I use to view any mail sent via hMailer.

Comment: Also remember it is very inlikely that any real mail server will accept mail from your hMailer server as it will assume its a spam source. You have to use it for local testing only

Answer (score 0):

The PHP mail() function doesn't support smtp authentication, which generally results in an error when connecting to public servers like the one you are trying to connect to. With hmailserver installed, you still need to use a library like PHPMailer which you can autheticate with.

Follow the steps here to setup phpmailer with gmail:
http://blog.techwheels.net/tag/wamp-server-and-phpmailer-and-gmail/

I've successfully sent email using gmail on (wamp/hmailserver/phpmailer).

```
<?php
  require_once ("class.phpmailer.php");
  $sendphpmail = new PHPMailer();
  $sendphpmail->IsSMTP();
  $sendphpmail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $sendphpmail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
  $sendphpmail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $sendphpmail->Port = 465;
  $sendphpmail->Username = "your@gmail.com";
  $sendphpmail->Password = "gmail_password";
  $sendphpmail->SetFrom('your@gmail.com','blahblah');
  $sendphpmail->FromName = "From";
  $sendphpmail->AddAddress("recipient@gmail.com"); //don't send to yourself.
  $sendphpmail->Subject = "Hello!";
  $sendphpmail->Body = "<H3>Check out www.google.com</H3>";
  $sendphpmail->IsHTML (true);
  if (!$sendphpmail->Send())
  {
    echo "Error: $sendphpmail->ErrorInfo";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Message Sent!";
  }
?>
```

Hope this helps others as well. Took me a few hours of googling and compiling answers from places while facing this issue.